# Function App not reading local.settings.json file with user secrets in Azure Functions v4

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I've looked around and I'm surprised no one else has asked this yet, but I am trying to use User Secrets with my Azure Function app (.NET 6, v4). The value is never populated with I run locally from Visual Studio.

`Function1.cs`

```cs
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var secret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mysecret");

            return new OkObjectResult($"Secret is: {secret}");
        }
    }
```

`local.settings.json`

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

`secrets.json`

```json
{
  "mysecret": "test1",
  "Values:mysecret": "test2"
}
```

`FunctionApp1.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <UserSecretsId>24c7ab90-4094-49a9-94ef-c511ac530526</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The endpoint returns: "Secret is: " and I would expect it to return either "Secret is: test1" or "Secret is: test2"

However, when I change my `local.settings.json` to this it works:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "mysecret": "test3"
  }
}
```

How can I get the user secrets to pass to local.settings.json correctly? I'm guessing they don't show up as environment variables.

Answer (score 6):

**TLDR:**

Might not be the best thing to do but it can be solved like this. I have done this a few times as well when there are settings that I want to check in. However if you do have settings that can be checked in you might reconsider adding them in their own class unless they should be overridden during deployment.

In my opinion you should keep `local.settings.json` and not try to replace this with `appsettings.json` since some values are usually needed to make it run like these:

```
"Values": {
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
},
```

Install NuGet `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets`

Set `local.settings.json` `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.

Modify `Program.cs` to look like this for .NET 5 <. Tested up to .NET 7:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
     {
         if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
         {
             config.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json");
             config.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
         }
     })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        var connectionString = hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        var configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
        
        var settings = new Settings();
        configuration.Bind(settings);
        services.AddSingleton(settings);
    }
    )
    .Build();

host.Run();

public class Settings
{
    public ConnectionStrings ConnectionStrings { get; set; } = new ConnectionStrings();
}

public class ConnectionStrings
{
    public string DefaultConnection { get; set; } = "";
    
}
```

The only thing really needed is below but I like to show more complete examples from the real world:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
 {
     if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
     {
         config.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json");
         config.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
     }
 })
```

You can now inject any `Settings` you have from the constructor and they will be overridden if a secret is present.

```
public class TimerTrigger
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly Settings _settings;

        public TimerTrigger(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ApplicationDbContext dbContext, Settings settings)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TimerTrigger>();
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _settings=settings;
        }

        [Function("TimerTrigger")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] MyInfo myTimer)
        {
            if (myTimer is not null && myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
                _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
                var defaultConnection = _settings.ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection;
```

**Long answer:**

ASP.NET Core web apps created with `dotnet new` or Visual Studio generates code similar to this for .NET 7:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

[WebApplication.CreateBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication.createbuilder) initializes a new instance of the [WebApplicationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder) class with preconfigured defaults. The initialized `WebApplicationBuilder (builder)` provides default configuration and calls [AddUserSecrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.usersecretsconfigurationextensions.addusersecrets) when the EnvironmentName is [Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.environmentname.development):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows#register-the-user-secrets-configuration-source

The method `AddUserSecrets` is located in the namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` from package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.usersecretsconfigurationextensions.addusersecrets?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets/

If we then look at how `Environment variables` works:

> Environment variables are used to avoid storage of app secrets in code
> or in local configuration files. **Environment variables override
> configuration values for all previously specified configuration
> sources.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows#environment-variables

Given that `local.settings.json` is meant to be local and the default `.gitignore` created when you add a Azure Functions project explicitly ignores it and therefore work like secrets:

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# Azure Functions localsettings file
local.settings.json
```

> The app secrets aren't checked into source control.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows#secret-manager

However if you still want to use the Secret Manager tool and secret storage read my TLDR.

Example values:

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "Movies:ServiceApiKey": "--SECRET--"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "--SECRET--"
  }
}
```

secrets.json:

```
{
  "Movies": {
    "ServiceApiKey": "12345"
  }
}
```

Reading values:

```
var moviesApiKeyConfig = _config["Movies:ServiceApiKey"];
var moviesApiKeySettings = _settings.Movies.ServiceApiKey;
var moviesApiKeyEnvironmentVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Movies:ServiceApiKey");
```

As you can see `IConfiguration` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` picks up secrets as expected but `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` does not. Also as expected from documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`secrets.json` is file used by [Secret Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows#secret-manager) which is for Development environment only. To store your secrets you have several choices for example provide them as [app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal) or use [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app).

Comment: Hi Guru, I am trying to get the value to populate from secrets.json when debugging locally, not when I deploy to an Azure App Service. Unless, are you saying that I should be populating that value using Azure Key Value locally?

Comment: If you want to add a secrets.json, in VS you can simply right-click the Azure Function in the Solution Explorer and select Add Secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, my conclusion is that User Secrets do not work with Azure Functions using .Net6 or .Net7. I have tried but unable to get it to work even though when the function starts the console will display "Found xxxxx.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration."

Here is a [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2413) that mentions the problem. Within that same issue is a [step-by-step set of instructions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2413#issuecomment-1260415071) to make the User Secrets load by reading the file into the IConfiguration pipeline.

I chose not to alter the startup pipeline and instead use Azure KeyVault binding in the local.settings.json. For example:
"SuperSecret": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://XXXXXXXX.vault.azure.net/secrets/SuperSecret/)"

Using Azure KeyVault allows the secret to be safe during development and requires no changes in production. Just make sure when you develop locally that your [Default Credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet) has access to the Azure KeyVault and [grant access to your function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli) once deployed.

Comment: Woot! That's my step-by-step set of instructions 

Answer (score 0):

Updating my csproj like this solved it for me

```
<None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
 </None>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, UserScrets started working like in older .NET Versions after adding `"DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"` in launchSettings.json. `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"` was not sufficient.

launchSettings.json:

```
    {
      "profiles": {
        "FunctionApp Local": {
          "commandName": "Project",
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local",
            "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Local",
          }
        }
      }
    }
```